# Example of OUTPUT clause to get Identity with ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm reading that using the OUTPUT clause is probably the best way to retrieve the Identity of a newly inserted record.  I'm pretty sure I could write a stored procedure and call that but my business objects use dynamically generated sql so having to use a stored procedure would be problematic.  Can anyone show me how to use ado.net to execute a single input statement with the output clause and get the returned Identity value?  It looks like it might not be possible to do it exactly this way but I thought I'd ask...

EDIT: Okay so it was easier than I thought... I thought I had to output to a table variable at first.  But the way I am doing it now isn't working quite right as it is returning the Identity 'before' inserting the new record.  Here is the statement I was just testing with:

```
INSERT Test (F1)
OUTPUT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
VALUES ('Testing')
```

Every time I do this it gives me back a result one number lower than what the value of the last inserted record's Identity actually is.  I would just add 1 to the result, but of course that won't work when I'm going between tables and the last result was from a different table.

I'm wondering if I should use IDENT_CURRENT('Test') and add 1 to that since it will be handled as a single transaction and I shouldn't have to worry about concurrency issues.

Any thoughts on how to get the correct result returned though?

Comment: Are you asking how to return @@IDENTITY as an output parameter of stored procedure, presuming there was an insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your identity field name is **Id**, then use like this:

```
INSERT Test (F1)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES ('Testing')
```

Value returned by `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will change AFTER the `insert` and obviously `OUTPUT` finish

**Or** keep it simple:

```
INSERT Test (F1)
VALUES ('Testing')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and you shouldn't even know what is the identity field.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing although it was a little more work because I don't necessarily know the name will be Id.  Unfortunately, I thought I wouldn't have any trouble getting the value back via a ReturnValue SqlParameter but I still haven't gotten that to work...

Comment: Yeah, I was also trying to avoid the second method to keep my code simple as possible (otherwise I would have to wrap it in a transaction to ensure there are no concurrency issues).  But in any case, I did end up doing the work to be able to use INSERTED, and I just realized I can just use ExecuteScalar() to get the value back.  All is good in the world again :)

Comment: Second is completely transactional. Other transactions never interfere wint `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function.

Comment: It's not transactional unless you put it in a transaction.  It's quite possible that someone else could insert a record between the time you inserted yours and got the value back.  Or am I missing something here?  I don't think that I am but feel free to correct me if so.

Comment: @BrandonMoore Yes, you're missing. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx - here states: Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column **in the same scope**. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch.

Comment: Ah, yes now I remember noticing that already but I had forgotten.  Thanks!